# How do I share the random number generator in numpy c-api?

Tags: c++, numpy, random, montecarlo

I wrote a Python program for Monte Carlo simulations that calls numpy functions that makes use of the built-in random number generator (e.g., `np.random.normal()` or `np.random.choice()`) and also imports some c++ functions (compiled using the standard numpy c-api) which also make use of a random number generator.

However, in order to be statistically correct, I need that both the numpy and numpy c-api functions use the same random number generator.

I presume I should pass the python random number generator to the c-api functions, or vice-versa.

How can I make sure that all the functions use the same pseudo random number generator?

Comment: Implement a random number function in your C++ code, use it in numpy instead of the python one and use the same in C++. E.g. `int get_random_number(void);`

Answer (score 1):

Old question but currently there is a working example in the documentation of numpy for extending the random distributions. It shows how to reuse a generator in the [examples](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/examples/cython/extending_distributions.pyx.html)
. I hope this helps.

Comment: that is specific to `cython`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is. Im assuming that you were interfacing the c++ functions via cython. If so then the  examples in that doc page should show generator reuse using the numpy c-api

Comment: thanks for your reply, but no, I wasn't using cython.